# USB Driver for ASUS ROG Strix X570-F Gaming motherboard

Tags: windows-7, usb, device-driver, microcontroller

I'd like to use USB 3.0 drivers on a Windows 7 install onto an ASUS ROG Strix X570-F Gaming motherboard. But, ASUS doesn't provide USB 3.0 drivers for this motherboard, and I don't find any information telling what is the chipset/controller that is in use.
I found some drivers that works, from Riolin Limited (never heard of them), but these come from "strange" sources and I don't find the original source of these drivers.

Could you tell me where I can find USB 3.0 drivers that are designed for this motherboard, from a secured genuine source ?
If not, where I can find the Riolin Limited website, to download their latest USB 3.0 drivers ?
And if not, what is the controller/chipset that drives the USB 3.0 ports on this motherboard ?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the user manual, it always contains a list of hardware components used on the board. In this case it contains a list of ports that are connected to the CPU and which are connected to the X570 chipset. But as you are using an outdated OS I am not sure if you will find the required drivers. IMHO an upgrade to Windows 10 (still possible for free) is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Latest drivers, signed by Riolin Limited:
https://winraid.level1techs.com/t/solution-win7-8-1-drivers-for-usb-3-0-3-1-controllers-of-new-amd-chipset-systems/33603

You have two USB 3 controllers.
"First" USB 3 controller is built into AMD X570 chipset.
"Second" USB 3 controller is built into AMD Ryzen CPU.

Microsoft is extremely powerful company, that is why AMD "can not" provide W7 drivers for chipsets newer than AMD X470 and processors newer than AMD Ryzen 3000 series.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/64497)

Comment: Thank you, but these are also "strange" sources that we cannot be confident with, but these are always good to know.